# How to add text under image with bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a template I'm trying to config, I don't know much about bootstrap but I'm slowly getting it as I research. I'm trying to put text under each image without offsetting the images on the bottom. (first time posting so excuses my noob)

[image]

```
<div class="container" id="projects-animate">
    <div class="row row-padded">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h2 class="fh5co-section-heading to-animate">Projects<span class="fh5co-border"></span></h2>
                <p class="to-animate">Libero velit fugit blanditiis tempora repellat iste inventore amet quaerat ex aliquid sint labore placeat esse.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-push-1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12 fh5co-project to-animate">
                    <a href="images/work_1.jpg" class="image-popup">
                        <div class="fh5co-overlay-text">Project no. 1</div>
                        <div class="fh5co-overlay"></div>
                        <img src="images/work_1.jpg" alt="Free HTML5 Template" class="img-responsive">
                    </a>
                    <div class="caption" class="col-md-3"><p>HELLLO</p></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12 fh5co-project to-animate">
                    <a href="images/work_2.jpg" class="image-popup">
                        <div class="fh5co-overlay-text">Project no. 2</div>
                        <div class="fh5co-overlay"></div>
                        <img src="images/work_2.jpg" alt="Free HTML5 Template" class="img-responsive">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12 fh5co-project to-animate">
                    <a href="images/work_3.jpg" class="image-popup">
                        <div class="fh5co-overlay-text">Project no. 3</div>
                        <div class="fh5co-overlay"></div>
                        <img src="images/work_3.jpg" alt="Free HTML5 Template" class="img-responsive">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12 fh5co-project to-animate">
                    <a href="images/work_4.jpg" class="image-popup">
                        <div class="fh5co-overlay-text">Project no. 4</div>
                        <div class="fh5co-overlay"></div>
                        <img src="images/work_4.jpg" alt="Free HTML5 Template" class="img-responsive">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12 fh5co-project to-animate">
                    <a href="images/work_5.jpg" class="image-popup">
                        <div class="fh5co-overlay-text">Project no. 5</div>
                        <div class="fh5co-overlay"></div>
                        <img src="images/work_5.jpg" alt="Free HTML5 Template" class="img-responsive">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12 fh5co-project to-animate">
                    <a href="images/work_6.jpg" class="image-popup">
                        <div class="fh5co-overlay-text">Project no. 6</div>
                        <div class="fh5co-overlay"></div>
                        <img src="images/work_6.jpg" alt="Free HTML5 Template" class="img-responsive">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please reformat the question to make it more readable(The Screenshot part onwards).

Comment: When you set text to all the images, it will fit in right? Like **[one here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/vfnksddf/1/)**.. You dont want that.. What is your expectation?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this `div` inside your column div :

```
<div class="carousel-caption">
    <h3>Example headline.</h3>
</div>
```

Just like this for all images by removing the `div` with the `class="caption;"` because you also have a bug there, you cant include twice `class` inside on html element. The right way is to write a class and separating them with space between just like this class="class1 class2" :

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12 fh5co-project to-animate">
                    <a href="images/work_1.jpg" class="image-popup">
                        <div class="fh5co-overlay-text">Project no. 1</div>
                        <div class="fh5co-overlay"></div>
                        <img src="images/work_1.jpg" alt="Free HTML5 Template" class="img-responsive">
                    </a>
<div class="carousel-caption">
    <h3>Example headline.</h3>
</div>
                </div>
```

You can play up with the padding or the header tag to make it as big as you want and place it where you want.